# How do I protect routes on my front end with Passport.js and Axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, passport.js, react-router-dom

I am a bit confused with react-router-dom v6 and using passport.js for protecting my routes. I have a session established with passport.js, however, I am not sure how to set up protected routes with authentication from Passport.js.

My login page calls the following function when the submit button is pressed:

```
    e.preventDefault();

    login(data)
      .then((response) => {
        toast.success(response.data.message);
        setData({ username: "", password: "" });
        navigate("/dashboard");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) {
          toast.error(err.response.data.message);
        } else if (err.request) {
          toast.error(err.request);
        } else {
          toast.error(err.message);
        }
      });
  };
```

This calls the login() function, which is contained in my loginAPI.js file on my front end.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/",
  timeout: 1000,
  withCredentials: true,
});

export async function login(data) {
  if (!data.username || !data.password) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("Data is missing"));
  }

  return await instance.post("/login", data);
}
```

Which in turn calls my login.js file in my routes/api folder on my back end.

```
var passport = require("passport");

router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/login-failure",
    successRedirect: "/login-success",
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

Everything authenticates properly, and redirects me to /dashboard upon authentication from Passport, however, that is due to the `navigate("/dashboard");` in my handleOnSubmit function. I can still access my dashboard without having to login as my app.js file is set up as follows:

```
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How would I protect the dashboard route if the user hasn't logged/been authenticated with react-router-dom v6? Thanks!

Comment: Does the new [authentication](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) docs and demo help at all with the basic gist of using an auth wrapper around the components you want to protect?

Comment: I looked it over prior to posting this, however, I was still confused on using this documentation in combination with passport.js and axios. If the session is created and the cookie stored, I wasn't sure how my front end would know that.

Comment: How does it know it now without an auth wrapper or private route component?

Comment: In my login.js file, the failureRedirect ``login-failure`` is declared in my index.js as 

```app.use("/login-failure", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Invalid Credientals" });
});
```

and my /login-success route

```app.use("/login-success", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Logged successfully" });
});
```
On my front end handleOnSubmit it waits for the success or error as shown above.

Comment: Oh, so you don't store any state in the frontend React app on successful authentication? Is the idea then to check on each route/navigation if the user is still authenticated or do you have a way to listen for authentication changes?

Comment: I actually haven't gotten to that part yet. I just finished the authentication backend. I had to redo that portion of my app after I wrote it using json web token and being advised that it was an unsecure method, I switched to passport.js. Most of my code I've written has been handled by the backend, and now I'm at the point where I'm binding things up.

Comment: I guess from here I can only say that you may want to store in app state (redux, context, etc..) that the user is authenticated, and this is used to access routes in the frontend. If you are storing cookies or returning tokens, check these when the app starts to know if a user should be logged out. Additionally, if using tokens, these should be sent with each request to the back end and validated, and if a token is now expired, return a error response (403) to the frontend to log the user out there (to invalidate route access).

Comment: This is just *some* ways to handle it though, and your solution depends on your specific needs and environment. I think you've a bit to do first before you're ready to start locking down routes/routing.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I am storing cookies and sessions currently. I'll do some research into checking authentication in app state. Thanks!